# Why doesn't this calculation work?

Tags: c#, operator-precedence

I was throwing together a quickie program to take mainframe output blocked in 133 byte lengths, all ending with a CRLF, and it was working except for my calculated number of lines in the output.  Because the output size was X pages of 133 bytes with 2 bytes (CRLF) at the end, I was calculating the line count as:

```
lineCount = fileLength - 2 / 133;
```

For a file length of 3194, that works out to 24 lines.  Take 3194, subtract 2 for the CRLF and you get 3192, and that is divided by 133 to come up with 24.  Simple!  The crazy thing is, I was getting the `lineCount` equal to the `fileLength`!

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After examining this several times, I finally hit on it!  It's a matter of the infamous **Order of Operations**!

```
lineCount = fileLength - 2 / 133;
```

If I evaluate this from left to right, according to my description above, it works fine, but I happen to be a human, not a CPU.  Different rule!  The computer processor has to use a different rule: MiDAS: multiplications, divisions, additions and subtractions.

My code was calculating 2 / 133, which for integers equals 0.  It was then subtracting that 0 from fileLength, and of course set lineCount to that value.  I am ancient of days, sort of, and should have known better from the start, but I guess I was in a hurry.  The correct code?

```
int lineCount = ((fileLength - 2) / 133);
```

So, remember MiDAS and you will be Golden!

NOTE: it's more complicated than this, actually.  The full rule encompasses parentheses and exponentiation.  For an expanded look at this check Wikipedia for **[Order of Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)**.

In the US the mnemonic is more like: PEMDAS - Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally - and refers to Parentheses, Exponents, Multiplications, Divisions, Additions and Subtractions.

Comment: "I happen to be a human" - not sure, you seem to be very cheap calculator :)

Comment: Even better than a wikipedia article, [here is the specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) showing how C# handles the order of all operations. MiDAS won't help you do `var result = 6 << 7 % someVar++ * 7;`